# Adding Row & submitting data via ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I wondered if anybody could point me in the right direction. I have a single web page which has the following table:

**Heres my Table*:*

```
<table id="staff" class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Email Address</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="email" placeholder="Email (Optional)">
      </td>
      <td><a href="#">save</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4">
        <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary btn-lg" id="addRow">Add Another Member</button><a href="addresident" class="pull-right" style="margin-top:10px;">Skip this step (Don't worry, you can add them later)</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

This produces 1 row, once the user has entered the information the user can click save and then beneath the table is a button for adding a new row. Once clicked the row immediatley appears beneath the last row and the user can carry on adding their members of staff.

My question, which method is best for storing those members of staff in the database?

**Here's my jquery**
I've had a go at the jquery but this is from another post and some of it applies when generating a new row but the inputs are wrong. Also i am slightly confused on how after clicking add new member the previous row will save to the database..

```
<script>
function addTableRow(jQtable) {
    var lastId = jQtable.find("tr:last td:first input").attr("data-id");
    var newId = parseInt(lastId) + 1;

    var row = $('<tr />');

    for (var i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
        var thisId = newId + i;
        var cell = $('<td />');
        var input = $('<input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" data-id="' + thisId + '" />');
        cell.append(input);
        row.append(cell);
    }

    row.append('<td><a href="#">save</a></td>');
    jQtable.append(row);
}

$('#addRow').click(function() {
    addTableRow($('#mans'));
});

$(function () {
    $('table').on('click', 'tr a', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parents('tr').remove();
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Each time that the button is clicked, you get the input that has been entered. You then send that input data to your server with an AJAX request. On the server side, you run a query to add that data to your database. On the client's end, you can generate the table row with the entered data and insert it. You then clear the values of your input fields and start over again.